# Export HTML web site to Scorm compliant

Tags: html, scorm

I have developed web site using html,js,jquery,css. How do i export this website to SCORM Compliant. Is there any easy way to get.
Thanks,
Thirupathi

Answer (score 8):

I'm making the assumption you do not have your file in a SCORM compliant package...

Ensure your website is SCORM compliant by using the correct schema definition files based on the version you are using (1.2 or 2004). You can download a schema manifest template [here](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/content-packaging/xml-schema-definition-files/).

Once you have created a package including definition files along with your own files, upload it to [SCORM Cloud](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud/). This will allow you to see how your SCORM package is running through the useful error logs.

Comment: imsmanifest.xml file is enough or do i create any other?Please let me know..i am in confusion and very new to this

Comment: You will basically need all the files from the manifest template download (link in my post). Then add your own files to this template. Since you are new to SCORM, I suggest you take a look at some of the examples [here](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/).

Comment: Thanks to ur reply...and is there any step by step tutorial to make it easier to me.....

Comment: I wrote a post on my blog a little while back with some links to help someone [get started with SCORM](http://surinder.computing-studio.com/post/2011/11/30/SCORM-Point-of-View-From-A-Novice.aspx). 

Unfortunately, there aren't any step-by-step tutorials. Hope this helps.